# MVC5 create user without certain columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can one change the default ApplicationUserManager, so that it won't try to add to "PhoneNumber", "PhoneNumberConfirmed" and "TwoFactorEnabled" columns in the db? I do not need those columns, so I have them removed as well as all the views/methods that are connected with them. And although I can't find anything else in the project code, ApplicationUserManager still tries to add those columns.

Comment: Are those columns nullable?

Comment: Are they nullable in the data model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot remove those columns from the database. The default implementation of [`IdentityUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identityuser(v=vs.108).aspx) has those columns in it so you can't remove them (at least not without getting the source code for Identity and removing them yourself.